# Polynomial Data Fitting for Two Unknown Equation

Tags: fitting, polynomial

I have a kind of data and want to find the equation(poly coeff) of given data. For example equation for given sample data is simple `a^2*b+10`

```
a\b    5    10    15
________________________
3|    55   100   145
4|    90   170   250
5|   135   260   385
6|   190   370   550
```

What is the correct algorithms?

Comment: Is it always an exact polynomial with no error? Do you have an upper limit on the degree? Is it a bivariate polynomial $P(a,b)$ or is this additive $P(a)+Q(b)$? What kind of output do you need? Are coefficients sufficient, or do you need it written as an equation?

Comment: @Glen_b No It is not an exact polynomial.Yes I have an upper limit of degree 3-4

Comment: Looking more closely, your generating poly is bivariate, not additive, so I assume that's what you want in output. Note that with only 3 different $b$-values you can't fit higher than a quadratic in $b$, and similarly $a$ is limited to cubic in this example. Further, if there's noise/inexact fit, you don't want to use up all the error d.f. with interactions, so on your example you can't even fit (in R notation) `poly(a,3)*poly(b,2)`, since that has $4\times 3$ coefficients for 12 points. If you're after sparse models you might consider using the LASSO or similar methods.